# Problema configuracion en symfony 2.8 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2, composer

Hola comunidad estoy teniendo un inconveniente con symfony 2.8
esto lo probé con varias versiones de composer y php.

Actualmente estoy con composer 2.0.11 y php 7.3.

Este es el **`composer.json`**:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "alexacrm/php-crm-toolkit": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.6",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/translation-bundle": "^1.3",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.6",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^1.9",
        "oneup/uploader-bundle": "~1.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Me devuelve este error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  9m                                                                           
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

esto mismo me pasa en este proyecto tanto en *Windows* como en *Ubuntu* al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Me devuelve

```
PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/**-symfony-backend/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 654
PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/***-symfony-backend/vendor/oneup/uploader-bundle/Oneup/UploaderBundle/DependencyInjection/OneupUploaderExtension.php on line 266
PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/***-symfony-backend/vendor/oneup/uploader-bundle/Oneup/UploaderBundle/DependencyInjection/OneupUploaderExtension.php on line 266
PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/***-symfony-backend/vendor/oneup/uploader-bundle/Oneup/UploaderBundle/DependencyInjection/OneupUploaderExtension.php on line 266
PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/***-symfony-backend/vendor/oneup/uploader-bundle/Oneup/UploaderBundle/DependencyInjection/OneupUploaderExtension.php on line 266
```

Los fragmentos que dice en ese código es:

```
/home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/a-symfony-backend/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 654

                    ->validate()
     /* linea 654 */->ifTrue(function ($v) { return ('fingers_crossed' === $v['type'] || 'buffer' === $v['type'] || 'filter' === $v['type']) && 1 !== count($v['handler']); })
                    ->thenInvalid('The handler has to be specified to use a FingersCrossedHandler or BufferHandler or FilterHandler')
                    ->end()



**home/rodrigo/Documentos/candoit/a-symfony-backend/vendor/oneup/uploader-bundle/Oneup/UploaderBundle/DependencyInjection/OneupUploaderExtension.php on line 266**

        protected function getValueInBytes($input)
    {
    // see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php
    $input = trim($input);
    $last = strtolower($input[strlen($input) - 1]);
    switch ($last) {
    case 'g': $input *= 1024;
    /* linea 266 */ case 'm': $input *= 1024;
    case 'k': $input *= 1024;
    }
    return $input;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución a esto fue usar específicamente php 7.0 y composer 1.0.0